# SSRS Report Date Range should limit Only 30 days

Tags: reporting-services

I am new to SSRS and I have to create a report with
1. Startdate and Enddate that can be only 30 days apart, It should throw an error message  "Startdate and Enddate must be less than 30 days apart"
2. Cannot be a date in the future.

Thanks in Advance.

Date : 02/18/2020:

Hi, This one worked in the past and its deployed but all of a sudden it is started throwing an error.
 In the Tablix properties I have to check these 3 conditions =IIF(DATEDIFF("d", Parameters!startDate.Value, Parameters!endDate.Value) > 30 AND Parameters!startDate.Value > Today() AndAlso Parameters!endDate.Value > Today() AND Parameters!startDate.Value >= Parameters!endDate.Value, True,False) . If I choose end date as todays date it is throwing a message but it is also displaying data. Please help me. It worked earlier, it used to show only message saying date is future date. Now it is displaying data also. I don't want the data to be displayed. TIA.

Comment: hellow, yous seem to ask for others to do your job. please show more details like the code and the problem to solve. If no more precise tag than reporting-services is available, please provide a link to the official site of the tool you are  speeking about. Thanks

Comment: There's not a built-in way to display custom error messages. You could HIDE the table and show an text box with you `Startdate and Enddate must be less than 30 days apart` message if the dates are more than 30 days apart. `=IIF(DATEDIFF("d", Parmeters!START_DATE.Value, Parmeters!START_DATE.Value) >= 30, True, False) `

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am getting the data even I choose more than 30 days and also it is displaying the message from textbox : "Startdate and Enddate must be less than 30 days apart". How can I restrict to not displaying the data. TIA.

Comment: To hide a table (or any object), you would use the **Hidden** property. Set it to True to hide or False to display the table. Use a similar one for the message but with the True and False switched. `=IIF(DATEDIFF("d", Parmeters!START_DATE.Value, Parmeters!START_DATE.Value) >= 30, True, False)`

Comment: Thank you so much, It worked. And for future dates I checked as below Parameters!START_DATE.Value < Now() or Parameters!endDate.Value < Now() it is throwing an error when I select future date. Thank a ton.

Comment: @Hannover Fist,I am getting one error. In the Tablix properties I have to check these 3 conditions  =IIF(DATEDIFF("d", Parameters!startDate.Value, Parameters!endDate.Value) > 30
AND Parameters!startDate.Value > Today() AndAlso Parameters!endDate.Value > Today()
AND Parameters!startDate.Value >= Parameters!endDate.Value, True,False) . If I choose end date as todays date it is throwing a message but it is also displaying data. Please help me. It worked earlier, it used to show only message saying date is future date. Now it is displaying data also. I dont want the data to be displayed. TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two parameters startdate and enddate, for startdate create a dataset using the following CTE:

```
;with dates ([startDate]) as (
Select convert(date,DateAdd("d",-60,(getdate()))) as [startDate] -- looks up todays date and subtracts 60 days
union all 
Select dateadd(day, 1, [startDate])
from dates
where [startDate] <= getdate() -- limits date not to be in the future
```

)
select [startDate]
from dates
option (maxrecursion 32767) -- Don't forget to use the maxrecursion option!

This would be the Available Values for your startdate parameter.

For enddate create a dataset using the following CTE:

```
; WITH dates([EndDate]) AS (SELECT CONVERT(date, DateAdd([d], - 59, (getdate()))) AS [EndDate]
```

UNION ALL
SELECT        dateadd(day, 1, [EndDate])
FROM            dates
WHERE        [EndDate] <= getdate()/* Put the end date here */ )
SELECT        [EndDate]
FROM            dates OPTION (maxrecursion 32767)

This would be the Available Values for your enddate parameter. you then need to apply/add two filters:

[EndDate] > [@startdate]

and

[EndDate] <= expression "=DateAdd("d",30,Parameters!startdate.Value)"

These two parameters limit the date range two within 30 days of each other and cannot be in the future, although no error message would never be required to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Date Range for the parameters by various techniques, but not all of them satisfies all the conditions.
Now, my idea can solve the future date problem and also date range problem.
You create 4 parameters namely Date, End, Start, EndRange

1.**Date**: choose Name Date, Datatype Date/Time and visible. No Available and Default value.

2.**End**: Choose Name End, Datatype Date/Time and visible. No Available values but click on Default values, choose Specify values and then click on Add button.
You will see a blank text area, end of that area you will see a function(Fx) symbol. Clicking on that a new window is open Set expression for: Value. In that enter this expression: **=DateAdd("d",30,Parameters!Date.Value)**

3.**EndRange**: Choose Name EndRange, Datatype Date/Time and Hidden. No Available values but click on Default values, choose Specify values and then click on Add button.
You will see a blank text area, end of that area you will see a function(Fx) symbol. Clicking on that a new window is open Set expression for: Value. In that enter this expression: **=iif(Parameters!End.Value > DateAdd("d",5,Parameters!Date.Value), DateAdd("d",5,Parameters!Date.Value), iif(Parameters!End.Value > Today(), Today(), Parameters!End.Value))**

4.**Start**: Choose Name Start, Datatype Date/Time and Hidden. No Available values but click on Default values, choose Specify values and then click on Add button.
You will see a blank text area, end of that area you will see a function(Fx) symbol. Clicking on that a new window is open Set expression for: Value. In that enter this expression: **=DateAdd("d",0,Parameters!Date.Value)**

Also, in the Stored Procedure or the query, declare two parameters,

1. @Date DATETIME,
2. @EndRange DATETIME
   and then in the where condition enter as,
   **[Column_Name] >= @Date and [Column_Name] <= @EndRange**

Now, you are all set to check this date range report.
For example I have created 5 days range report with start date, end date entered by the user and the Actual end date with 5 days range selected by default system.

Scenario 1:
[User selects Start Date and End Date within 5 days range.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3vXR.png)

Scenario 2:
[User Enter Start Date but end date is in future, system will limit the end date to current date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzk4U.png)

Scenario 3:
[User Enter Start and End Date within the date range, then as normal dates.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMIE2.png)